# Can Hibernate Oracle12c dialect used hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

I see that Oracle12c dialect is available only for hibernate 5.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle12cDialect.html

Sadly I can't upgrade the hibernate from version 4.3.11.Final
and I would like to know if there's a way to "backport" or force to use this dialect in hibernate 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Use `Oracle10gDialect`, since Oracle 12c is backwards compatible, you just won't use new features.
- Grab the source from Hibernate 5.4.5: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.4.5/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle12cDialect.java